# Refactoring unused props in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In the code below

```
<FormSelectBox environment setAvgOrderCountEnum={setAvgOrderCountEnum} inputSelectOff={inputSelectOff} avgOrderCountEnum={avgOrderCountEnum} />
```

I get the following typescript error

[image: ts error]

I resolved the error by creating a variable that stores all my unused props

```
  // FormSelectBox unused props
  const nullProps = {
    foreignDeliveryEnum: null,
    setForeignDeliveryEnum: null,
    foreignPackageWeightEnum: null,
    setForeignPackageWeightEnum: null
  }
```

and used the spread operator to include `nullProps` in my component instance

```
<FormSelectBox environment setAvgOrderCountEnum={setAvgOrderCountEnum} inputSelectOff={inputSelectOff} avgOrderCountEnum={avgOrderCountEnum}  {...nullProps} />
```

Is there a better typescript way to refactor my code and handle this issue?

The code for my `FormSelectBox` is below

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { avgOrderCountEnumList, foreignDeliveryEnumList, foreignPackageWeightEnumList } from '../utils/common'

const FormSelectBox = ({ setAvgOrderCountEnum, setForeignDeliveryEnum, setForeignPackageWeightEnum, inputSelectOff, avgOrderCountEnum, foreignDeliveryEnum, foreignPackageWeightEnum, environment }) => {
  const cases: any = setAvgOrderCountEnum ? avgOrderCountEnumList() : setForeignDeliveryEnum ? foreignDeliveryEnumList() : setForeignPackageWeightEnum ? foreignPackageWeightEnumList() : null

  const liList = cases.map((cases, index) => {
    return (
      <li key={index} onClick={() => {
        setAvgOrderCountEnum ? setAvgOrderCountEnum(cases) : setForeignDeliveryEnum ? setForeignDeliveryEnum(cases) : setForeignPackageWeightEnum ? setForeignPackageWeightEnum(cases) : null
      }}>
        {
          environment ? (
            <span className="select-option environment">
              {cases.name}
            </span>
          ) : (
            <span className="select-option">
              {cases.name}
              {cases.country}
              {cases.weight}
            </span>
          )
        }
      </li>
    )
  })

  const optionList = cases.map((cases, index) => {
    return (
      <option key={index} value={setAvgOrderCountEnum ? cases.id : setForeignDeliveryEnum ? cases.id : setForeignPackageWeightEnum ? cases.id : ''}>
        {cases.name}
        {cases.country}
        {cases.weight}
      </option>
    )
  })

  return (
    <>
      <div className="form-select-box-dim" onClick={() => {
        inputSelectOff()
      }}></div>
      <div className={`form-select-box ${setForeignDeliveryEnum ? "FD" : setForeignPackageWeightEnum ? "FPW" : ""}`}>
        <ul>
          {liList}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <select onChange={(e) => {
        if (setAvgOrderCountEnum) {
          const selectCase = cases.find(c => c.id === e.target.value)
          setAvgOrderCountEnum(selectCase)
        }
        if (setForeignDeliveryEnum) {
          const selectFD = cases.find(c => c.id === e.target.value)
          setForeignDeliveryEnum(selectFD)
        }
        if (setForeignPackageWeightEnum) {
          const selectFPW = cases.find(c => c.id === e.target.value)
          setForeignPackageWeightEnum(selectFPW)
        }
      }} value={avgOrderCountEnum ? avgOrderCountEnum.id : foreignDeliveryEnum ? foreignDeliveryEnum.id : foreignPackageWeightEnum ? foreignPackageWeightEnum.id : ''}>
        {setAvgOrderCountEnum && <option value=''>월 평균 출고량을 선택해주세요.</option>}
        {setForeignDeliveryEnum && <option value=''>주요 배송국가를선택해주세요.</option>}
        {setForeignPackageWeightEnum && <option value=''>주요 배송 상품의 무게를선택해주세요.</option>}
        {optionList}
      </select>
    </>
  )
}

export default FormSelectBox

FormSelectBox.propTypes = {
  setAvgOrderCountEnum: PropTypes.func,
  setForeignDeliveryEnum: PropTypes.func,
  setForeignPackageWeightEnum: PropTypes.func,
  inputSelectOff: PropTypes.func,
  avgOrderCountEnum: PropTypes.object,
  environment: PropTypes.bool
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored the default props with the following

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { avgOrderCountEnumList, foreignDeliveryEnumList, foreignPackageWeightEnumList } from '../utils/common'

interface FormProps {
  environment?: boolean,
  inputSelectOff? :any,
  avgOrderCountEnum? :any,
  setAvgOrderCountEnum?: any,
  foreignDeliveryEnum? : any,
  setForeignDeliveryEnum?: any,
  foreignPackageWeightEnum? : any,
  setForeignPackageWeightEnum?: any,
}


const FormSelectBox: React.FC<FormProps> = ({environment, inputSelectOff, avgOrderCountEnum, setAvgOrderCountEnum, foreignDeliveryEnum, setForeignDeliveryEnum, foreignPackageWeightEnum, setForeignPackageWeightEnum }) => {
  const cases: any = setAvgOrderCountEnum ? avgOrderCountEnumList() : setForeignDeliveryEnum ? foreignDeliveryEnumList() : setForeignPackageWeightEnum ? foreignPackageWeightEnumList() : null

  const liList = cases.map((cases, index) => {
    return (
      <li key={index} onClick={() => {
        setAvgOrderCountEnum ? setAvgOrderCountEnum(cases) : setForeignDeliveryEnum ? setForeignDeliveryEnum(cases) : setForeignPackageWeightEnum ? setForeignPackageWeightEnum(cases) : null
      }}>
        {
          environment ? (
            <span className="select-option environment">
              {cases.name}
            </span>
          ) : (
            <span className="select-option">
              {cases.name}
              {cases.country}
              {cases.weight}
            </span>
          )
        }
      </li>
    )
  })

  const optionList = cases.map((cases, index) => {
    return (
      <option key={index} value={setAvgOrderCountEnum ? cases.id : setForeignDeliveryEnum ? cases.id : setForeignPackageWeightEnum ? cases.id : ''}>
        {cases.name}
        {cases.country}
        {cases.weight}
      </option>
    )
  })

  return (
    <>
      <div className="form-select-box-dim" onClick={() => {
        inputSelectOff()
      }}></div>
      <div className={`form-select-box ${setForeignDeliveryEnum ? "FD" : setForeignPackageWeightEnum ? "FPW" : ""}`}>
        <ul>
          {liList}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <select onChange={(e) => {
        if (setAvgOrderCountEnum) {
          const selectCase = cases.find(c => c.id === e.target.value)
          setAvgOrderCountEnum(selectCase)
        }
        if (setForeignDeliveryEnum) {
          const selectFD = cases.find(c => c.id === e.target.value)
          setForeignDeliveryEnum(selectFD)
        }
        if (setForeignPackageWeightEnum) {
          const selectFPW = cases.find(c => c.id === e.target.value)
          setForeignPackageWeightEnum(selectFPW)
        }
      }} value={avgOrderCountEnum ? avgOrderCountEnum.id : foreignDeliveryEnum ? foreignDeliveryEnum.id : foreignPackageWeightEnum ? foreignPackageWeightEnum.id : ''}>
        {setAvgOrderCountEnum && <option value=''>월 평균 출고량을 선택해주세요.</option>}
        {setForeignDeliveryEnum && <option value=''>주요 배송국가를선택해주세요.</option>}
        {setForeignPackageWeightEnum && <option value=''>주요 배송 상품의 무게를선택해주세요.</option>}
        {optionList}
      </select>
    </>
  )
}

export default FormSelectBox

FormSelectBox.propTypes = {
  environment: PropTypes.bool,
  inputSelectOff: PropTypes.func,
  avgOrderCountEnum: PropTypes.object,
  setAvgOrderCountEnum: PropTypes.func,
  foreignDeliveryEnum: PropTypes.object,
  setForeignDeliveryEnum: PropTypes.func,
  foreignPackageWeightEnum: PropTypes.object,
  setForeignPackageWeightEnum: PropTypes.func,
}
```

Comment: yes this is correct, for making it much better you can better create another interface name OptionalProps and extend it from there but this is perfect too.